# Is there anyway to access the base path of an uploaded file with Rust WASM?

Tags: rust, webassembly, seed

Does WebAssembly have the same issue as native JS(for very valid security reasons) that it cannot access the base/root path of any given uploaded file or selected folder? I want to write a Rust UI app with `seed` and using `rfd` (or its previous iterations `nfd/nfd2`) that users can indicate a file path so the application can install certain files in the correct place.

Otherwise can `seed` compile to a local `.exe` instead of a web based app, and therefore have proper access to the file system?

Thanks

Comment: Considering access to the filesystem is dependent on the execution environment (in this case the browser) and not necessarily the language, I would guess no.

Comment: What do you mean by "access the base/root path"? WebAssembly has no access to the filesystem, if that is what you mean. In fact, any external data in WebAssembly has to be passed to it from the browser/JavaScript side, so all the same limitations apply.

Comment: I figured as much Herohtar. I'll look at using a native rust GUI crate instead of `seed`. Cheers.